# How can I tell the Compiler which Members of a Type cannot be trimmed in a given context?

Tags: c#, generics, msbuild, system.text.json, publish-trimmed

Given the following utility method that parses a JSON file:

```
public static T? ReadJsonFile
<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicProperties)] T>
(String file)
{
    using var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead($"./Resources/{file}");
    return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(fileStream);
}
```

I want to tell the compiler/trimmer, that none of the public properties of `T` can be [trimmed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/prepare-libraries-for-trimming?pivots=dotnet-8-0), even if they are not used in the code.

Does my usage of the `DynamicallyAccessedMembersAttribute` accomplish this goal?

Compiling still produces a trim warning for `Deserialize`.
Why is that, and how can I 'safely' get rid of it?

Is there a better/cleaner way of achieving what the method does using other overloads of `Deserialize`?

Comment: I guess using a `Type` instance here would help - however: you are using System.Text.Json - the suggested way of using that with trimming is using source generation for a JsonSerializerContext [as described in the blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation)